# YAML serialization library for C++?

Tags: c++, serialization, yaml, persistence, boost-serialization

YAML seems like a great format for configuration files & data binding persistent objects in human-readable form...

Is there a C++ library that handles YAML? Does `Boost::Serialization` have plans for a YAML option?

**EDIT: I would prefer an OO library.**

Comment: I wish Cereal, which is great otherwise, would have the possibility to parse\write yaml. It doesnt have to use all the features of yaml, just the equivalent of a simple json tree.

Comment: an experimental implementation: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-archive-yml

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A quick search gave me this: [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp)

Answer (score 6):

Try the YAML component from the [BOOST vault serialization library](https://github.com/boost-vault/serialization).

**EDIT 2014**: A recent development, https://groups.google.com/d/msg/boost-devel-archive/mhT7qIh1nsI/uXAuXFAWrxQJ

**EDIT 2019**: Didn't try it yet, but this seems to be a serious take: https://github.com/rwols/yaml-archive

**EDIT 2024**: I developed my own YAML serialization archive for Boost Serialization.

https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-archive-yml

Comment: I recently try to made it work, to make it compile, 1) I had to adapt the library to the newer version of the Boost.Serialization Archive framework (mostly updating names of internal classes), 2) update namespace to use the now Spirit.Classic ...

Comment: ... 3) change Boost tuples code, 4) move a lot of code to `.hpp` since some instantiations didn't work. 5) Yet, I couldn't make it work since the NVP wrapper doesn't work with arrays, finaly I made it output a serialization which looks correct, however I cannot deserialize it. After a lot of work, I get an error on the use of Spirit grammar (something about wrong use of `rule_t` to unary expression `!S >> '=' >> !S`. I can't do anymore. Maybe it will pay off to start from scratch on top of the XML archive case.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, please if you use it let me know how it did it for you and post some example if possible,

https://code.google.com/p/google-summer-of-code-2008-boost/downloads/list

UPDATED link (as 2014), it seems to point to the same files as the BOOST vault answer.