# Parse YAML Files in C++

Tags: c++, yaml

I want a simple tutorial to show me how to load a yaml file and parse the data. Expat style would be great but any solution that actually shows me the data in some form would be useful.

So far I ran multiple tests in the `yaml-0.1.1` source code for C and I either get an error, no output whatsoever, or in the `run-emitter.c` case. It reads in the yaml file and prints it to `STDOUT`, it does not produce the text via `libyaml` functions/structs. In the cases with an error I don't know if it was because the file was bad or my build is incorrect (I didn't modify anything...) The file was copied from yaml.org

Can anyone point me to a tutorial? (I googled for at least 30 minutes reading anything that looked relevant) or a name of a lib that has a good tutorial or example. Maybe you can tell me which `libyaml` test loads in files and does something with it or why I got errors. This document does not explain how to *use* the file--only how to load it:

http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML#Documentation

Comment: Please, C and C++ are not the same. There are excellent examples of solutions for each, but as you see they are very different. I guess from the tags you want C++ more than C. If you want C++, ask for C++. Asking for C solutions can often make a program more confusing.

Comment: Does anyone know what "expat" style means in the question? OP said: "Expat style would be great but any solution that actually shows me the data in some form would be useful."

Answer (score 77):

Try [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) (as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244784/yaml-serialization-library-for-c)) for a C++ parser.

Disclosure: I'm the author.

Example syntax (from the [Tutorial](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial)):

```
YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("config.yaml");

if (config["lastLogin"]) {
  std::cout << "Last logged in: " << config["lastLogin"].as<DateTime>() << "\n";
}

const std::string username = config["username"].as<std::string>();
const std::string password = config["password"].as<std::string>();
login(username, password);
config["lastLogin"] = getCurrentDateTime();

std::ofstream fout("config.yaml");
fout << config;
```

Comment: What is the setup required to use [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp)? Do I just have to download the header files and include them in my C++ program?

Comment: @BruceWayne you have to build the library and link it to your project.

Comment: Unfortunately yaml-cpp is hardly maintained.  Releases are unfrequent, sometimes buggy (which distros such as Debian worsen by not updating enough from upstream), and as of early 2018 the latest release still uses `auto_ptr` which forbids the use of yaml-cpp in any C++17 project.

Comment:  I am proven wrong, the 0.6.0 release was made a couple of hours after my previous comment.

Comment: @akim How do you build this thing? I've spent hours on this and I can't seem to get it to build. I keep getting undefined reference its driving me crazy.

Comment: I have not tried yet.  I'm waiting for it to appear in the distros I depend upon :/  I don't want to have to vendor it.

Comment: @akim: I don't think you're wrong; IME, yaml-cpp **is** not maintained _at all_. From what I can tell, the latest 0.6.0 and 0.6.1 releases [don't even build](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/554), neither on Linux nor on macOS. I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: @ssc that's not true; please see the issue you're linking to.

Comment: And to be clear: I don't work a lot on this project any more, but it *does* still work, and I do accept patches that are easy to verify, and I'd *love* if someone stepped up to be a more active maintainer :)

Comment: @JesseBeder: submitted the best patch I could muster, see issue. PS: what is `getCurrentDateTime()` ?

Comment: @ssc thanks! And that was just an example of a function someone might have written.

Comment: As of Dec 5, 2019, I found the yaml-cpp library essentially unusable. It threw exception after exception on valid yaml code, double check by external validators. In the end I'm back to looking for a more stable c++ yaml library.

Comment: @granitdev have you filed a bug?

Comment: I went through the tutorial, I can't seem to find how to use the ```DateTime``` MSVC says it is an undeclared identified... is there a namespace missing?

Comment: In 2020, we got vcpkg support, so it's as simple as `vcpkg install yaml-cpp`

Comment: Is there a full example including headers and libraries?

Comment: For anyone wanting a potential solution for what `getCurrentDateTime()` might look like on Linux, see my C answer here: [Retrieve Linux Time using struct timespec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71889097/4561887). My original source code for it is in my eRCaGuy_hello_world test repo as `timing_clock_gettime_full_demo.c`. The code works perfectly in C++ too. The `time_str` variable I create prints out as `Fri Apr 15 14:05:12 2022 -0700`, which is the same format `git` uses when you `git commit`. Print the same thing at the command-line with `date +"%a %b %-d %H:%M:%S %Y %z"`.

Comment: please provide config file for this

Comment: How does the config.yaml look like?

Answer (score 12):

I have written a tutorial at
http://wpsoftware.net/andrew/pages/libyaml.html.

This covers the basics of using libyaml in C, using token-based and event-based parsing. It includes sample code for outputting the contents of a YAML file.

Answer (score 11):

C example - parsing YAML tree to a [glib "N-ary tree"](http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/glib/glib-N-ary-Trees.html):

```
#include <yaml.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>

void process_layer(yaml_parser_t *parser, GNode *data);
gboolean dump(GNode *n, gpointer data);



int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char *file_path = "test.yaml";
    GNode *cfg = g_node_new(file_path);
    yaml_parser_t parser;

    FILE *source = fopen(file_path, "rb");
    yaml_parser_initialize(&parser);
    yaml_parser_set_input_file(&parser, source);
    process_layer(&parser, cfg); // Recursive parsing
    yaml_parser_delete(&parser);
    fclose(source);

    printf("Results iteration:\n");
    g_node_traverse(cfg, G_PRE_ORDER, G_TRAVERSE_ALL, -1, dump, NULL);
    g_node_destroy(cfg);

    return(0);
}



enum storage_flags { VAR, VAL, SEQ }; // "Store as" switch

void process_layer(yaml_parser_t *parser, GNode *data) {
    GNode *last_leaf = data;
    yaml_event_t event;
    int storage = VAR; // mapping cannot start with VAL definition w/o VAR key

    while (1) {
        yaml_parser_parse(parser, &event);

        // Parse value either as a new leaf in the mapping
        //  or as a leaf value (one of them, in case it's a sequence)
        if (event.type == YAML_SCALAR_EVENT) {
            if (storage) g_node_append_data(last_leaf, g_strdup((gchar*) event.data.scalar.value));
            else last_leaf = g_node_append(data, g_node_new(g_strdup((gchar*) event.data.scalar.value)));
            storage ^= VAL; // Flip VAR/VAL switch for the next event
        }

        // Sequence - all the following scalars will be appended to the last_leaf
        else if (event.type == YAML_SEQUENCE_START_EVENT) storage = SEQ;
        else if (event.type == YAML_SEQUENCE_END_EVENT) storage = VAR;

        // depth += 1
        else if (event.type == YAML_MAPPING_START_EVENT) {
            process_layer(parser, last_leaf);
            storage ^= VAL; // Flip VAR/VAL, w/o touching SEQ
        }

        // depth -= 1
        else if (
            event.type == YAML_MAPPING_END_EVENT
            || event.type == YAML_STREAM_END_EVENT
        ) break;

        yaml_event_delete(&event);
    }
}


gboolean dump(GNode *node, gpointer data) {
    int i = g_node_depth(node);
    while (--i) printf(" ");
    printf("%s\n", (char*) node->data);
    return(FALSE);
}
```

Comment: where did you get `yaml.h`

Comment: `yaml.h` is provided by [libyaml](https://github.com/yaml/libyaml/blob/master/include/yaml.h)

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative to `yaml-cpp` and `libyaml` there is [rapidyaml](https://github.com/biojppm/rapidyaml). Here's an example.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <ryml_std.hpp>
#include <ryml.hpp>

std::string get_file_contents(const char *filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!in) {
        std::cerr << "could not open " << filename << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    std::ostringstream contents;
    contents << in.rdbuf();
    return contents.str();
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{
    std::string contents = get_file_contents("config.yaml");
    ryml::Tree tree = ryml::parse_in_place(ryml::to_substr(contents));
    ryml::NodeRef foo = tree["foo"];
    for (ryml::NodeRef const& child : foo.children()) {
        std::cout << "key: " << child.key() << " val: " << child.val() << std::endl;
    }
    
    ryml::NodeRef array = tree["matrix"]["array"];
    for (ryml::NodeRef const& child : array.children()) {
        double val;
        child >> val;
        std::cout << "float val: " << std::setprecision (18) << val << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**config.yaml**

```yaml
foo:
  bar: a
  barbar: b
  barbarbar: c

matrix:
  array:
    - 0.045533736417839546
    - 0.16564066086021373
    - 0.028658520327566304
    - 0.009133486414620372
    - -0.5801749091384203
```

#### Update

Be aware that this project uses submodules recursively, that is why "Download ZIP" option on GitHub will not work. Use git

```bash
git clone --recurse-submodules -j8 https://github.com/biojppm/rapidyaml.git
```

Considering you have `rapidyaml` cloned in **thirdparty/rapidyaml** here is a minimal cmake configuration .

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(so_answer VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_subdirectory(thirdparty/rapidyaml)

add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_include_directories(example PRIVATE thirdparty/rapidyaml/src)
target_link_libraries(example ryml)
```

Comment: I am using windows os and how to include rapidyaml in cmakelists

Comment: @AMAR, it works on Windows. I added example of CMakeLists.txt to my answer. Make sure you clone all submodules.

Comment: I run the above example(downloaded git repositiry as you mentioned) but it's giving c4/std/string.hpp No such file or directory                                    ```set( yaml "C:/rapidyaml/src")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${yaml})
``` I am using cmakelists.txt

Comment: if any one use above library make sure package next to cmake and use add_subdirectory to the cmake.

Comment: sir thanks for you're response and finally i am able to read the yaml file

Comment: If inside of yaml file metrix data present then that time how  can we  convert to matrix

Comment: ```dist2:
- - 0.045533736417839546
  - 0.16564066086021373
  - 0.028658520327566304
  - 0.009133486414620372
  - -0.5801749091384203
height: 480
rms: 1.6671979326607804
width: 640```    get_file_contents gives data as strings and then I want to convert to float ,matrix like .

Comment: @AMAR there's an >> operator that you might want to use - I added it to my example. Though it messed up the precision, so better to pull such values as strings. If you have more questions, then it'd better to create a new question on SO.

Comment: sir, Thank you for you're response and I got it .

Comment: How to write dynamic data to yaml file , For example different data type like str, int and cv::Mat data . I tried to write but it's accepting string data only, is rapidyaml storing data as a string ?

Answer (score 5):

A Google Code Search (now defunct) for "yaml load lang:c++" gave this as the first link: [demo.cc](https://github.com/wilhelmtell/libyamlpp/blob/master/demo/begin/demo.cc):

```
#include <iyaml++.hh>
#include <tr1/memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

// What should libyaml++ do when a YAML entity is parsed?
// NOTE:  if any of the event handlers is not defined, a respective default
// no-op handler will be used.  For example, not defining on_eos() is
// equivalent to defining void on_eos() { }.
class my_handler : public yaml::event_handler {
    void on_string(const std::string& s) { cout << "parsed string:  " << s << endl; }
    void on_integer(const std::string& s) { cout << "parsed integer:  " << s << endl; }
    void on_sequence_begin() { cout << "parsed sequence-begin." << endl; }
    void on_mapping_begin() { cout << "parsed mapping-begin." << endl; }
    void on_sequence_end() { cout << "parsed sequence-end." << endl; }
    void on_mapping_end() { cout << "parsed mapping-end." << endl; }
    void on_document() { cout << "parsed document." << endl; }
    void on_pair() { cout << "parsed pair." << endl; }
    void on_eos() { cout << "parsed eos." << endl; }
};

// ok then, now that i know how to behave on each YAML entity encountered, just
// give me a stream to parse!
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    tr1::shared_ptr<my_handler> handler(new my_handler());
    while( cin ) {
        try { yaml::load(cin, handler); } // throws on syntax error

        catch( const runtime_error& e ) {
            cerr << e.what() << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```