# Read a YAML file using a C script

Tags: c, yaml

I would like to read a thin YAML file using a simple C program. I beleve the best way for this is to use the follow library: Pyyaml.org.

After reading the wiki page, I have try to use some examples here:
http://pyyaml.org/browser/libyaml/branches/stable/tests/
But for a noob like me, it is not very simple to understand.

If for example I get this more simple YAML file (named **test.yml**):

```
test:
  - {conf: hi}
  - {conf: test}
  - {conf: abc}
```

How can I do to do somethig like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /* I do not really see how to load the file here... */

  char *conf[3] = {"hi", "test", "abc"}; /* configuration of the YAML file */

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    printf("content: %s\n", conf[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

...but from the given YAML file?

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: The word "script" is not very well defined, but I think most people would agree that C is not a scripting language :)

Comment: Also, PyYAML is a Python library. Good luck using it from C.

Comment: I think he means he wants to use the libYAML library which is what the linked tests are for (and also what PyYAML is based on)

Comment: Yes, it's about libYAML. I am looking at the second answer... thank you for the link!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse YAML Files in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365155/parse-yaml-files-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [second answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365155/parse-yaml-files-in-c-c/621451#621451) has a little bit better example of using the library to parse yaml file into something more useful.

Comment: Vote to close this question as duplicate instead!

Answer (score 2):

libyaml seems to be event based, which usually means it's tuned for speed and less for easy usability. And there aren't many examples around (at least for the original C code, the scripting language bindings are more popular). The source distribution has some sample code in the tests directory. The most comprehensive seems to be the [deconstructor example](https://bitbucket.org/xi/libyaml/src/6d5f97d2330147c286839bacfa0c66fac3992faf/tests/example-deconstructor.c). It's long but very well commented, so it's easy to follow.

Generally, I'm not sure how useful YAML is for C code. YAML's greatest strength is that it maps naturally to the data types used by scripting languages like Python and Perl - lists and dictionaries, nested to arbitrary levels. The ability to trivially serialize such nested structures into YAML makes it attractive. I'm curious why you need YAML for C code.