# Serialize infinite -ary tree

Tags: data-structures, serialization, tree

Is there a way to serialize any tree?

Mind maps are trees. Text is serial. I wonder if there is an elegant way to serialize trees.

An n-ary tree [can be serialized](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialize-deserialize-binary-tree/), if we represent the absence of a node as NULL. But that is not intuitive. We do not think in terms of "two absences of new ideas".

Trees can be serialized [recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7866218/6417519). But that solution is complicated, making use of lines and indentation. Git's commit history feels similar.

Trees, as graphs, can be described by their [nodes and edges](https://graphology.github.io/serialization.html#format). Somehow that comes across as describing the behavior and history of a tree than itself to me, which may not even make sense.

Is there a well-known, simple, elegant way to serialize infinite -ary trees? Equivalently, is there an innate, implicit representation for trees, and trees alone? On a related note, how can I define a tree purely generatively, instead of "graphs that satisfy such and such qualities"? Or perhaps, is there a textbook on such topics that a non-CS major can read up on?

Comment: I'd wager that more than half of all standardized serialization formats represent trees of unbounded arity.  s-expressions, JSON, XML, ASN.1, avro, protobuf, RIFF, etc. etc.

Comment: Note that ordered infinite-arity trees are isomorphic to binary trees.  Just call the left link "first child" and the right link "right sibling".