# How can one get/print details of a node from its value using yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

How can I read this YAML file with yaml-cpp:

```
sensors:
  - id: 5
    hardwareId: 28-000005a32133
    type: 1
  - id: 6
    hardwareId: 28-000005a32132
    type: 4
```

How can one get/print details of id = 5 (i.e. type and hardwareID) in a long list of such items efficiently?

Comment: Did you try the tutorial? https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/master/docs/Tutorial.md The first example shows a file being opened and parameters being read.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse YAML Files in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365155/parse-yaml-files-in-c)